# python3 --version - выводит python 3.8.5, при этом я уже установил 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, консоль

уважаемое сообщество! Собственно, проблема, с которой я столкнулся описана в заголовке. Установил через sudo apt install python 3.9, до этого стояла версия 3.8.5. При этом, насколько я понял, старая версия не удалена и у меня на данный момент две версии python. В pycharm выбрал новый интерпретатор, проект с учетом этого обновился. Но в консоле ubuntu, при просмотре версии python, я вижу только старую. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но PyCharm видит последнюю версию, о чем можно судить по PythonConsole
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскfжите, нужно ли мне было удалять старую версию или использоватm какую-либо другую команду для установки python 3.9, и почему по команде python3 --version я не вижу версии 3.9. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый простой способ - просто явно указать версию питона. То есть, вместо `python3 --verstion`, написать `python3.9 --version` и в других местах. Этот способ, как по мне, самый лучший, потому что точно ничего в системе не сломать.

Если посмотреть на файл python3, то можно понять, что это просто симлинка на правильную версию питона. А значит обновить ее на подходящую не составит труда.

```
rm /usr/bin/python3
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python3
```

Но можно даже так - добавьте в  `~/.bash_aliases`

```
alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.9'
```

в результате пользовательские программы будут использовать свежий питон, а внутрисистемные - старый. Но аккуратно, могут быть разные эффекты.

Но есть другой способ, через update-alternatives - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt . Он считается правильным и рабочим.

Comment: Вас понял, спасибо!